# Backdoor Roth IRA and "total basis in traditional IRA for 2022 and earlier years"

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira

Like many of you, I am currently preparing my taxes for 2023. I have a question about Backdoor IRA and a particular line in my 2022 Tax Return.

Each year, I have contributed to a Traditional IRA and Converted to Roth IRA, here is the exact schedule:

| Date | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/29/21 | Contribution | 6000 |
| 12/30/21 | Conversion | -6000 |
| 1/10/2023 | Contribution | 6000 |
| 01/11/2023 | Conversion | -6000.7 |
| 03/30/2023 | Contribution | 6500 |
| 04/03/2023 | Conversion | -6503.4 |
| 01/09/2024 | Contribution | 7000 |
| 01/16/2024 | Conversion | -7007.07 |

In my 2022 Tax Return, Form 8606 Line 14 "total basis in traditional IRA for 2022 and earlier years" says $6,000. Should it say $0 given I have done only *clean* Backdoor IRA? Or is there something I don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

You had contributed $6000 in January 2023 which was counted as attributed to 2022 (you've made another contribution in March, presumably for 2023). That's the $6000 basis. You've converted it into Roth in 2023, so you had $6000 basis for 2022.

Comment: So the basis is basically telling the IRS "I know I contributed 12,500 in one year but it's because 6,000 of it (the basis) was for previous tax year (2022)"?

Comment: From the IRS perspective you've contributed it in 2022.